# “Not a tab” symbol should be added to the “privileges” link in profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, hyperlinks, privileges-page

Due to opening a link “Privileges” in the profile page settings as a new page (not a tab of profile page), there should be a special symbol like for “Question Subscriptions” link:

> [image: not a tab]

Comment: I don't follow. The privileges link doesn't open in a new tab. Neither does the Question Subscriptions link for that matter. The icon is there to indicate that the link goes to *another site* (in this case, takes you to stackexchange.com).

Comment: @animuson What he's saying is that it shouldn't look like simply another tab in the preferences, if it isn't.

Comment: @animuson I didn’t say about **new** (browser?) tab. I said about tab inside profile settings page. Both: privileges and subscriptions pages require that you need to use “go back” (browser) button to return to profile page. That’s not needed for any other options.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog thanks for clarification. You as always understand me better than others :)

Comment: Ah, well then, I'm changing this to a feature request, because a different icon would make more sense to clarify that. The icon we used there is a universal "external site" icon, not a "you're leaving this area" icon and I don't think it'd make sense to put it next to Privileges.